# Hourly Segregate pg_stat_statements On Reader Instance

Tags: postgresql, monitoring, amazon-aurora, postgres-fdw, pg-stat-statements

Aurora Postgres 11.8
I have to segregate pg_stat_statements on an hourly basis on Reader instance.
On Writer instance it's simple, create a table and backup pg_stat_statements on an hourly basis and then clean up pg_stat_statements using pg_stat_statements_reset().

Since I can't create a table on Reader so need experts remarks for that, One thought is to create FDW table on Writer and copy data on an hourly basis but how to sync pg_stat_statements_reset() along with that on Reader? not look like a robust solution to have two separate cronjobs for copy and pg_stat_statements_reset().

Being from Oracle background I am tunned up for hourly ADDM reports.
pg_stat_statements is found to be a somewhat satisfactory alternate to ADDM.
I want to divide pg_stat_statements on an hourly basis to get a more in-depth analysis since a single summary of all busy and off-hours is less meaningful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thete are many possible soutions, choose one based on simplicity and how well it suits your setup.

My idea would be *not* to run `pg_stat_statements_reset()` at all, but calculate the difference between subsequent snapshots of the data. That saves you the trouble of synchronizing the two activities.

For the snapshot, my idea would be a (possibly NFS-mounted) directory on the standby into which you write a hourly snapshot with `COPY`, scheduled by a `cron` job.

Comment: Laurenz: Thanks for the reply.
I want to stick to FDW for the copy as it's simple for me and I can manage multiple reader stats in one writer this way.
As you said 'not to run pg_stat_statements_reset()' its good to calculate the difference for incremental columns like calls, total_time, rows etc.
but I fail to manger diff for group columns like min_time, max_time, mean_time etc. I want them on an hourly basis and can't get hourly max_time unless pg_stat_statements_reset().
Can you tell me an easy way out of it? or any way to do pg_stat_statements_reset() from writer to reader instances?

Comment: `mean_time` is easy - it can be calculated from `calls` and `total_time`, which are additive. You are right about the other columns; perhaps you can do without them or you live with the all-time-maximum values. `pg_stat_statements_reset()` doesn't modify the database, creates no WAL and is not replicated. It has to be run on the standby, and I know no way out from this.